# How to get the language code of an order?

Tags: magento2, localisation

With the order id, how to retrieve the language code from the order or from the user ?
(anything that looks remotely like EN, ES, FR, or en_UK, fr_FR).

For example : if the user has been on a website based on Magento 2.x , he browses the website in Russian, and he buys a chocolate bar ***Wonka Bar***. His order id is 13371337.

How could one get "ru_RU" later on (the user is not logged in anymore) programatically ?

Comment: is Russian a store in your website?

Comment: Yes, it is a language from a store in my website

Comment: Then I guess getting store id from order and then language code from store will work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this below code it will work based on customer IP placed but you need to create event sales order after(`checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`) and need to create the table in `sales_order` table.

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Observer;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class classname implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl) {
        $this->_curl = $curl;
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    { 
          $orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
          $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
          $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order') ->load($orderId[0]);
          $order->setLanguageCode($this->getCountryName())
          $order->save();
          return true;    
    }

    public function getCountryName() {
        $visitorIp = $this->getVisitorIp();
        $url = "freegeoip.net/json/".$visitorIp;
        $this->_curl->get($url);
        $response = json_decode($this->_curl->getBody(), true);
        $country_code = $response['country_code'];
        return $country_code;        
    }

    public function getVisitorIp() {       
        $remoteAddress = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress');
        return $remoteAddress->getRemoteAddress();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. Getting a language by geolocalisation will work 95% of the time, but sometime the users are browsing in another language, like a German living in England for instance.

Comment: Using Google Translate?

Comment: How many languages stores do you have on your site?

Comment: If this answer helpful for you means please accept the answer, It'll help others too.

Comment: I haven't used it in the end, but it may be the most appropriate answer for the stackexchange users who will land here.

Comment: I have used the store's language instead (see my answer). Thanks anyway, answer accpeted

Answer (score 0):

```
\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
                        ->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')
                        ->getValue('general/locale/code', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $order->getStore()->getStoreId())
```

This will get the store's language that has been used for the $order